# SSD options in /etc/fstab stop machine from booting

Tags: boot, ssd, fstab

I just recently installed 12.10 on a new Lenovo T430, and added [these options](http://janneinosaka.blogspot.com/2012/08/t430-and-ubuntu.html) in `\etc\fstab`:

> discard, relatime

To `\sda1` on which `\` is installed. When I rebooted, I got an error claiming that it couldn’t read `\`, and got thrown into a read-only shell, which necessitated booting from a rescue disk to revert to the original `fstab`.

**So:** What are the correct options for SSD, and how can I make sure I won't get locked out of the system again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my own SSD I use discard, noatime which seems to work, but with the /etc/fstab you have to make sure that no spelling errors are present or it can halt boot-up...

During initial boot hold down SHIFT key and go into recovery mode and from there you can enable read/write by selecting fix repo's and then drop to prompt to fix your /etc/fstab file...

Answer (score 2):

You used a backslash ("\") rather than a forward slash ("/"), which is [not allowed on Uinux-like systems like Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Representations_of_paths_by_operating_system_and_shell).

Answer (score 1):

You should not add whitespace in the options list. `discard,relatime` should be used instead of `discard, relatime`. While you are at it, you can remove `relatime` since this is the default setting for recent kernels.

To fix this error, you can boot from a Live CD, mount your root partition and edit the `/etc/fstab` file with appropriate permissions.